# Show that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n^\frac{1}{n} \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} (a_{n+1} / a_n).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I've been set the following question as part of my Real Analysis homework and I'm struggling with it:

Let $(a_n)_n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Show that:

$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n^\frac{1}{n} \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} (\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}) $$

I have reasoned that if the RHS takes value $\infty$ then the inequality is automatically satisfied so we can assume RHS $= \lambda < +\infty$

We got a hint in the lecture that went something like this: For $m \geq n$,

$a_m \leq a_n \lambda^{m-n} \Rightarrow a_m^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq (a_n \lambda^{m-n})^\frac{1}{n}$

And then taking supremums a and limsups but I'm confused at this point and I'm not really sure where to take t from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ in the RHS? Otherwise, it is false -- take $a_n = 2^{n}$, for instance.

Comment: Are you talking about my attempt? With $a_n = 2^n, \limsup (\frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n}) = 2$ so $a_m \leq a_n \lambda^{m-n}$ holds does it not?

Comment: No, I was talking about the statement you wanted to prove. Before your edit, it was false, as you had written $a_n+1$ instead of $a_{n+1} $.

Comment: Oh sorry, thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take everything to the power $\frac1m$, not $\frac1n$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. By assumption, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}\le\lambda+\epsilon$ for all $m\ge n$. Inductively this gives us
$$a_m\le(\lambda+\epsilon)^{m-n}a_n$$
for all $m\ge n$, and so
$$a_m^{1/m}\le(\lambda+\epsilon)^{1-n/m}a_n^{1/m}.$$
Now you can consider $n$ fixed, so $a_n^{1/m}\to1$ and $(\lambda+\epsilon)^{-n/m}\to1$ as $m\to\infty$. Hence
$$\limsup_{m\to\infty}a_m^{1/m}\le\lambda+\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: Hi Jason, I follow your argument right up until the last part. Could you please give some more detail on why the final stage implies the result?

Comment: If $L\le\lambda+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $L\le\inf_{\epsilon>0}(\lambda+\epsilon)=\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$, you have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq \lambda+\varepsilon$. Show that this imply that there exists $c$ independant of $n$ such that for $n$ large  we have $a_n\leq c( \lambda+\varepsilon)^n$.